# Issue in transforming python list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list like this:

```
highlights=
['Security Name % to Net Assets* DEBENtURES 0.04, Britannia Industries Ltd. EQUity & RELAtED 96.83, HDFC Bank 6.98, ICICI 4.82, Infosys 4.37, Reliance 4.05, Bajaj Finance 3.82, Housing De
velopment Corpn. 3.23, Grindwell Norton 3.22, SRF Sun Pharmaceutical 2.85, Bharti Airtel 2.82, DLF 2.64, Ultratech Cement 2.62, SKF India 2.45, Crompton Greaves Consumer Electricals 2.42,
 Avenue Supermarts 2.41, Axis ABB 2.35, Titan Co. 2.29, Kotak Mahindra 2.09, Cipla 2.05, Laurus Labs 2.04, Wipro 1.77, Happiest Minds Technologies 1.68, Canara 1.67, Shree 1.63, 1.59, Pid
ilite 1.50, Lombard General Insurance 1.48, Cholamandalam Investment 1.45, Tech 1.35, State of 1.31, Hindustan Unilever 1.30, Vardhman Textiles Larsen Toubro 1.24, Dabur 1.22, Neogen Chem
icals 1.10, Eicher Motors 1.09, Thermax 1.08, TATA Consultancy Services 1.05, Indian Railway Catering Tourism 0.98, Firstsource Solutions 0.97, Nestle 0.86, Asian Paints 0.84, Welspun 0.7
2, IndusInd 0.63, SBI Life 0.50, Deepak Nitrite 0.46, Adani Ports and Special Economic Zone 0.36, Gateway Distriparks 0.33, Bharat Forge 0.22, tREPS on G-Sec or t-Bills 2.81, Cash Receiva
bles 0.32, tOtAL']
```

and I am trying to convert it into a dataframe using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([highlights], columns=['C-Names'])
print(df)
```

It creates a dataframe however it stacks all data in a single row
something like this:

```
                                       C-Names
0  Security Name % to Net Assets* DEBENtURES 0.04
1  Axis ABB 2.35
2 Lombard General Insurance 1.48
.
.
.
```

when I check the length of the list it shows 1. what exactly is the issue in this? Am I doing something wrong? Please help

Comment: Looks like you have a list with just one string inside of it.

Comment: Your list has a single large string item.

Comment: What format do you want your data to have?

Comment: Would also be good if you told us how the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: @Djib2011 in a dataframe

Comment: @timgeb please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is one string. It should be more like this:

```
highlights = ['Security Name % to Net Assets* DEBENtURES 0.04', 'Britannia Industries Ltd. EQUity & RELAtED 96.83', 'HDFC Bank 6.98, ICICI 4.82, Infosys 4.37', 'Reliance 4.05']
```

Then it would work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(highlights)

df
    0
0   Security Name % to Net Assets* DEBENtURES 0.04
1   Britannia Industries Ltd. EQUity & RELAtED 96.83
2   HDFC Bank 6.98, ICICI 4.82, Infosys 4.37
3   R|eliance 4.05
```

Comment: Is there a way of making it like this? because I am getting it from somewhere else.

Comment: You would need to convert the comma in the string to " , ". So something like highlights = highlights.replace(",", "\',\'")